# Execution order in LET statements with IF clauses

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am unclear of the order in which statements are executed in a LET() statement.

My use case is a function which returns the number of rows in a database table: there is a quick way to get an estimate, or a much slower way to get an exact number. If the quick way produces a number of rows under 50, I want to run the slow way to get the exact number of rows, otherwise the estimate is fine.

Consider an example:

Cell A1 `=QUICK()` where QUICK() returns a non-zero integer in a rapid function.

Cell B1 =`IF(A1<50,SLOW(),A1)` where SLOW() is a very slow function

This works as I would expect, with SLOW() only getting called if A1 < 50.

BUT, if I try to do this all in one function:

Cell A1 `=LET(nr,QUICK(),IF(nr<50,SLOW(),nr))`

It seems that `SLOW()` is always executed, regardless of the value of `nr`, even if I add a dummy parameter which makes `SLOW()` dependent on `nr`.

Has anyone seen similar?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't misconstrued your example in an attempt to simplify it? It is true that variables defined within `LET` are always evaluated, whether they are then passed to the ensuing calculation or not. So, for example, `=LET(nr,QUICK(),zz,SLOW(),IF(nr<50,zz,nr)` would force an evaluation of SLOW(). However, in the example you give, SLOW() is not being passed as a variable to `LET`, so will not be evaluated.

Comment: Hmm I attempted to recreate this issue with something like `=LET(nr,1+1,IF(nr<2,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1000,1000),SEQUENCE(1000,1000,2)),nr))`, and the `MMULT` was clearly not evaluated.

Comment: Precisely my point.

Comment: @JosWoolley I cut & pasted directly from the formula bar. I am using a xll-based UDF to fire SQL queries to my database. `=LET(nr,rpiRiskQuery(H1,FALSE,E3),IF(nr<G2,rpiRiskQuery(H2,FALSE),nr))`. Now the function won't mean much to anyone, but you can see my LET construction. The first query H1 is quick, the 2nd query using H2 is SLOW (table has 115mm rows). G2 contains the value 5000. If I store the first query result in a cell (say H10), and call `=LET(nr,H10,if(H10<G2,SLOW(),H10)` then the SLOW does not get executed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you see if you step through with Formulas > Evaluate Formula? I tested with a valid UDF, and in the relevant evaluation step its result was just #N/A: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wauX9.png, suggesting that it wasn't evaluated to begin with.

Comment: I think it's slow because your `Quick()` isn't really that quick ;) It'll evaluate that first. How fast is your `Quick()` compared to the LET?

Also, what is Quick really doing?

Comment: @P.b Quick executes this query: `SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class where relname='mytablename'`. Slow executes: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytablename`. The first gives a rapid estimate of the rows in a table, the second is exact but takes a long time for a large table (it's a PostGres DB).

Comment: So executing Quick() in `A1` takes significantly shorter than executing it directly in the LET*? *if it returns smaller than 50.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour was being caused by the QUICK() function (coming from an xll) returning a single-value 1x1 array rather than a scalar.

Using @BigBen's example:

`=IF(TRUE,0,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1000,1000),SEQUENCE(1000,1000,2)))`

returns `0` immediately

Whereas `=IF({TRUE},0,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1000,1000),SEQUENCE(1000,1000,2)))`

returns a 1000x1000 array of `0`.

This is in itself odd, as this is NOT the result of `=MMULT(SEQUENCE(1000,1000),SEQUENCE(1000,1000,2))` either.

I'm using Excel Version 2302
Build 16130.20306

Further on this:

If I have a range A1:A2 that contains TRUE in each cell
and call `=IF(A1:A2,0,1)` I get an 1x2 array of `0`. This is what I would expect.

If I call `=IF(A1:A2,0,SEQUENCE(2,2))` I get a 2x2 array of `0`, which is certainly not what I would expect.

*Suspicion:*

Excel functions can only return scalars or r x c arrays. I am guessing array functions try and determine the dimensions of the result array first and then fill this array with the function result.

In an even more reduced form:
`=IF({TRUE;TRUE},1,{0,0})`

You might expect to get a 2x1 array of `1`, but instead you get a 2x2 array of `1`. Excel has (perhaps) executed both the *fnTrue* and the *fnFalse* options regardless of the value (TRUE/FALSE) of the test parameter, and then taken the smallest r x c array that would fit both. It then fills this array with either the result of *fnTrue* or *fnFalse*. In this example, for each row of the test, Excel is setting aside a 1x2 array, and then filling it with the answer.

If instead the function were `=IF({TRUE,FALSE},1,{0,0})` and Excel naively applied the test row-by-row, the first row (TRUE) would return `1` but the second `{0,0}`. Excel would have then have to re-allocate the return array, and go back and fill the empty cell in the first row result. So I am guessing the formula is parsed to work out the possible dimensions of the result and this seems to entail executing both functions.

At the very real risk of getting too hung up on this ... you can test this assertion by creating two VBA UDFs, *ifTrue()* and *ifFalse* and use `Debug.Print` to record when each is called. If you call the function `=IF({TRUE},ifTrue(),ifFalse())` you will see in the Immediate Window that BOTH functions are called.

Comment: That sounds kinda logic, that the possibility of an array containing different outcomes makes it evaluate both options, which influences the outcome. Great investigation.